# Postgres filter dynamic type (null or string)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a database table looks like the following:

| id | category | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | NULL | String |
| uuid | String | String |
| uuid | String | String |
| uuid | NULL | String |

I want to query the items based on categories:

```
select * 
from table
where category = $1
```

`$1` is a value given at run time, can be either `null` or `string` type.

The `=` operator only works for the category string I want, but when the category provided is null, the query will run into error (have to use `is null` for null comparison).

Comment: Is `$1` a PL/pgSQL variable or is this being created in some other language first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that one specific string can neither occur in the dataset nor the search string (e.g. the empty string) you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE COALESCE(category, '') = COALESCE($1, '')
```

or you can explicitly compare for both being NULL like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE
    category = $1
    OR
    (
        category IS NULL
        AND
        $1 IS NULL
    )
```